# realm, check schema version

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm for Android, I'm wondering how to get the current schema version. In their Migration example, the version is incremented then saved, but I need to check the version before doing any upgrade.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your purpose to do this? I can imagine maybe you just want to totally abandon some Realm which is below some certain version and create brand new one instead. In this case, migration is too complex. Simplest way came to my mind is just use a Realm with a new name instead, and try to delete the old one. No need to bother with the schema version.

Comment: I tried to debug the upgrade process by manually setting the schema value higher than current one, but sometimes I don't know which value is current

Comment: The `version` param from `Migration.execute(Realm realm, long version)` is the current Realm's version. Would this be helpful?

Comment: I know that, but that is when the migration is already triggered, if I know it beforehand then I can decide which schema value to set (to control whether it should migrate)

Comment: Realm doesn't have an API to get the schema version right now. Maybe nasty way is that you can throw a custom exception with the version in the `Migration.execute` and catch it. Why do you need to decide which schema value to set? Why not just update it to the latest one?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code to get the current schema version of Realm before migration.

```
Realm.init(context);
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
DynamicRealm realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfig);
long version = dynRealm.getVersion();//this will return the existing schema version
dynRealm.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Migration class from the example, you can see that they check for every version. The version parameter is the current version of the current realm. If you notice that after every if statement, the version is incremented.

```
if (version == desiredVersion){
   //Migration script
   version++;
}
```

In any way, you will need to write migration scripts for all versions whose changes need migration. Otherwise, the app will be crashed.