# Get realm old schema version during RealmConfiguration build

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

In my current project we have five different instances of realm for different porpoises. The main one's schema version is now 5 and we want to get rid of it and start the next one (schema version 6) completely clean, because we launch version 2.0.0 of the app and there were mayor DB changes.

The question is, is there a way to check the old schema version of a realm instance before building its new configuration?

We already tried defining a specific schema version to delete realm with `realmDeleteIfMigrationNeeded()` and providing a migration class for following versions. The problem with this approach is when a user has a version of the app with schema version below the one specify and update to an app version with a greater one an so we have a migration needed exception.

I also found here [realm, check schema version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419803/realm-check-schema-version), here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2645 and here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6049 a possible solution doing 'val realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfiguration)' and then 'getSchemaVersion()' but we really don't know how this could work as you have to provide a 'RealmConfiguration' when you actually have to set the schema version.

I will try to clarify my question, we have the following way of getting a realm instance

```
private val realmConfiguration = buildRealmConfiguration(realmInstance)

private fun buildRealmConfiguration(realmInstance: RealmInstance):
    RealmConfiguration {

    return realmInstance.run {
        val realmBuilder = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(getName())
            .schemaVersion(schemaVersion.toLong())

        if (this == RealmInstance.IN_MEMORY) {
            realmBuilder.inMemory()
        } else {
            getMigration(realmBuilder, this)
        }

        realmBuilder.build()
    }

fun getInstance(): Realm {
    return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration)
}
```

```
enum class RealmInstance(val instance: String, val schemaVersion: Int) {

    MAIN_DB(instance = "main_db", schemaVersion = 5),
    DB2(instance = "db2", schemaVersion = 1),
    ...

    fun getName() = instance

    fun getMigration(
        realmBuilder: RealmConfiguration.Builder, 
        realmInstance: RealmInstance
    ) {

        when (realmInstance) {

            MAIN_DB -> {
                /*
                Variable used to delete main_db Realm during migration from app version 1.x.x to version 2.0.0 due to a mayor schema change
                */
                val migrateToAppVersion2 = realmInstance.schemaVersion <= 4

                realmBuilder.apply {
                    modules(mainDbModule())
                    if (deleteRealm) {
                        deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    } else {
                        migration(realmMigration!!)
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

The ideal situation will be check the actual schema version of the DB before calling 'getMigration()' allowing us to always deleting realm if the old schema version belongs to v1.x.x of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RealmMigration` implementation to check old and new versions :

```java
public class CustomRealmMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

and add this to your `RealmConfiguration` builder :

```
RealmConfiguration.Builder()
//...
.migration(new CustomRealmMigration())
//...
.build()
```

Comment: We already use `RealmMigration` for migration (see `getMigration()` method in `RealmIntance`class) but that wasn't exactly the point we are looking. With the migration we can't delete a realm instance with `deleteRealm()` (it's not already build)

Comment: If we want to remove them the hard way (by deleting the realm files in the database folder) we will need a `context ` to search for the file (I personally think a `context ` should never be passing from class to class out of the view without a very reasonable motive)

I was asking for a more creative solution.

Comment: Can't you just delete all old entities in the RealmMigration ? It's tedious but it'll work ;)

Comment: You mean deleting them from the schema? Shouldn't that implies that we would have to add them all again? If you don't mean that, how would we do it?
I think of passing the actual builder to the migration class, build the configuration and use `getRealmDirectory()` to find and delete all that instance DB whenever is necessary but don't really know if it would work or if it is a good practice

Comment: If I get correctly what you want : if schema version is X you want to delete everything to get a fresh start. If so you could delete every classes like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36723295/1243048 and then create all your new classes. I'm I wrong ?

Comment: You are right that's exactly what I want to achieve but trying to use a method when I don't need to delete all my classes and then creating them again.

Comment: Also I don't know if it is a good practice to refer to an example in another language as in Java we don't have the same methods.
I will try to use the delete all realm files approach and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Realm via `DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfiguration)` to see the schema version. If it's smaller than 6, close the dynamic Realm, then call `Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration)`.

Comment: I actually saw this answer before, as I mention in the problem description, the problem with this approach is that you have to generate a Realm instance (dynamic in this case) but you have to supply a 'realmConfiguration' where you have to set the version. 

Doesn't that means that when you get its schema version it will return the one you just set in the configuration?

Comment: I don't think the DynamicRealm actually cares about your schema version property, because Dynamic Realm doesn't do schema validation. But the Realm file itself does have a schema version and it should be returning that